# Replace a match only till some other match is found

Tags: search, replace

Aiming to convert first row of a html table from  to  tags.

So, I wrote the following code.

```
(defun tdtoth ()
  (if (search-forward "</tr>" nil t)
      (while (search-forward "td" nil t)
        (replace-match "th" 1))))
```

And executed it while I was on  in the following text:

```
<tr>
  <td> Some text </td>
  <td> Another thing </td>
</tr>
```

The idea being search for `</tr>` only once and while that is not happening, replace every `td` with `th`

But that code does not work. What is wrong and how do I set it right?

Comment: Don't write that function if you don't need it in the context of some bigger program. Just narrow your buffer to the region `<tr>...</tr>`. Thereafter you can easily perform any replacements restricted to that region. Narrowing the buffer works as follows: Put point on `<tr>` and type `C-_` (the underscore stands for a space). That sets mark and therefore starts the region. Search for `</tr>` via `C-s` and type `C-x n n` for `narrow-to-region`.

Comment: @Tobias the function was doing several things together. This was one part of it. But I agree with your point. It would be quicker just to do it with narrowing, etc. in the buffer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After my comment about not needing the function in most cases I also want to give an answer to your actual question.

One of the many ways to replace all occurences of `td`-tags with `th`-tags starting at point and stopping at a closing `tr`-tag is shown below. The most important differences to your solution are:

- You need to keep point's position when you search for the end tag `</tr>` (e.g., with `save-excursion`).
- You need to restrict your search for `<td>` to the region between point and the found end position, e.g., with the `BOUND`-argument of `search-forward`.

```el
(defun dttoth ()
  "Replace dt by th starting at point and stopping at </tr>."
  (interactive)
  (let ((bound (save-excursion (search-forward "</tr>" nil t))))
    (when bound
      (while (re-search-forward "<[/]?\\(td\\)>" bound t)
        (replace-match "th" t nil nil 1)))))
```